# NameError: name '' is not defined - Seen after trying to get input

Tags: python, class, nameerror

I have been trying to make a test-ish sort of game to learn about classes and how they work. My program, which is:

```
    print('The Dark Tunnel 2: Electric Boogaloo')
    win = False
    class Room(object):

      def __init__(self, location):
        self.location = location

      def move(self):
        self.move = move
print(rooms[self.move])

      def look(self):
        self.look = look
        print(secrets[self.look])
    rooms = {'north': 'You are in a dark room.', 'south': 'You are in a bloody room.', 'west': 'You are in a wet room.', 'east': 'You are in a grungy room.'}
    secrets = {'north': 'There doesn\'t seem to be anything you missed.', 'south': 'There is an old coin by your feet.', 'west': 'There is too much water at your feet.', 'east': 'Is there someone behind those bars?'}
    while win == False:
      action = input('> ')
      if action in rooms:
        Room.move(action)
      else:
        Room.look(action)
```

After inputting 'north' which I thought would put out 'You are in a dark room' I got:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "program.py", line 20, in <module>
    Room.move(action)
    File "program.py", line 9, in move
    self.move = move
    NameError: name 'move' is not defined
```

Comment: The issue is exactly what the error says: you don't define `move`, and yet call it.

Comment: Unsure of what you're doing inside the `move` function.

Comment: In the move function I was trying to make it put out the value of whatever you entered in "action"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your `move` method to accept an argument called `move`, then you need to specify that parameter when you define the method:

```
def move(self, move):
    self.move = move
```

Except that your attribute `move` needs to have a different name from your method `move`; otherwise you are replacing the *method* `self.move` with the supplied value.

```
def set_move(self, move):
    self.move = move
```

Then you need to call it using an *instance* of `Room`, not the class itself.

```
r = Room('some location')
...
r.set_move(action)
```

Comment: Thank you. You are a true bro